# Erro "O servidor de automação não pode criar objeto" ao tentar usar ActiveX

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, activex

Alguém sabe me informar que tipo de erro é esse? Acontece quando tento instanciar o objeto:

```
var fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
```

Comment: Então eu já fui no IE em opções para internet na aba segurança e habilitei todos os ActiveX

Answer (score -1):

Adicionar o site nas opções de sites confiáveis
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]